# A question about analog IC vs digital IC

Tags: integrated-circuit

I don't have any experience in designing analog or digital ICs.

But from what I have read there must be a reason to call an IC analog or digital.

I have the following questions:

Does/Can an analog IC include any transistor which are operating in saturation region as switch?

Or similarly can a digital IC include any transistor which are operating in active/linear region?

Comment: There are no digital ICs, there are just ICs which can be conveniently modeled in a binary way when the inputs are kept within certain bounds. It's generally possible to run "digital" ICs in a analog regime, though it's not supported by the manufacturer. If you put feedback on a generic NAND/NOR gate, you can sometimes use it as a analog amplifier.

Comment: In the past, there where separare processes for creating ASICs with different goals in mind. You could call them digital and analoge if you wish. You can make digital parts in an "analoge" process but with speed penalty and you can make analoge parts in a "digital" process but with size and linearity penalty. These days, unless you have a big wallet and special purposes, you make everything in "digital" process.

Comment: what is "analoge" process ? what is "digital" process /. never heard that terminology.

Comment: Manufacturing process. The set of layers of different metals and oxides that make up a chip. Lots of chips include a mixture of analogue parts and digital parts; analogue-to-digital converters, for example. Or PLLs, on-chip voltage references, and so on.

Comment: @pjc50 Indeed. These days there is more emphasis on digital and you accept the overhead on your analog part.

Comment: @161776 Consider a CD and an casette tape. Can you store analoge data on a CD, yes, look up LaserDisc. Can you store digital data on an casette tape, yes, look up Commodore 1530 for the C64. Is CD more favorable for digital, yes. Is casette more favorable for analogue, yes. This is less evident if you look into different processes for ASICs but the analogy is still there, you can choose a process which is optimized for digital circuits and still make analog parts in it.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to your first question is yes. Many analog IC's also have transistors and even outputs that act like a switch. An example that I'm dealing with at the moment is the BISS0001, a PIR control IC which can switch one of it's pins fully high or fully low, with no inbetween (pin 2).

[image: BISS0001]

The second question is also likely yes. On a "purely digital" IC, you're unlikely to find any non-digital outputs, but its almost certain that it has transistors within it that are performing non-saturating functions. What those functions might be is anyone's guess, but for example the 74ls04 had some extra transistors that deal with some sort of compensation (i think?).

[image: 74LS04]

The way you define analog and digital hardware is somewhat blurred, because the transistors that make up the "digital" hardware are fundamentally analog devices.

Comment: That transistor, with 1.5k in base and 3K in collector, squares up the IN/OUT transfer curve. In other words, boosts the noise margin.

Answer (score 5):

Plenty examples of non-linear transistor operation in "linear" circuits. One very common example is Class AB output stages found in audio power amplifiers and also in a great many op-amps.
[image: Audio Class AB power amplifier]
Here, Q5&Q2 provides power to the speaker on the high-side swing, while Q4/Q1 provide power to the speaker on the low-side swing. It is classed as an analog circuit.

---

As for digital circuits actually running analog...a great many computers are driven from a crystal-controlled clock that employs an inverter-type Pierce oscillator. The oscillator starts off running linearly at power-up, and soon produces a pseudo-square output that becomes a digital clock signal:

[image: Pierce oscillator]

Comment: in your last example, is the Pierce oscillator one single IC?

Comment: Pierce can be as simple as one single transistor (plus some bias resistors). For the crystal oscillator example, it can be a P-channel MOSfet combined with a N-channel MOSfet, as in a 74HCU04 hex inverter IC. Or it is incorporated as one of very many microcontroller's functions, requiring two pins.

Comment: I need to see a "single" digital IC where some transistors are operating in linear region and most are in saturation region as switch. your last example is not that I guess. can you give such digital IC example where some transistors are operating in linear region and most are in saturation region as switch? ALL HAS TO BE in a single IC/single chip

Comment: Any "brown-out-detector" IC with digital output, yet an internal bandgap reference into analog comparator, has that mix.

Comment: @161776 That Pierce example oscillator *is* operating in hybrid linear/saturation. For small oscillations (at start-up), the PMOS/NMOS operates linearly via the "R" resistor. Oscillations grow in amplitude until semi-saturation. The following buffer gate provides a faster rise & fall time, saturated square wave.

Answer (score 1):

An [analogue switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogue_switch) is controlled digitally yet it can route analogue signals (like in an old fashioned telephone exchange). An analogue switch can also be used to switch digital signals so there is a great spread in its uses across the analogue and digital world.

At the end of the day there really is only analogue components and many digital circuits are analysed from the analogue perspective.

Examples of an analogue switch: -

[image]

Note that the switching elements are transistors and not relay contacts.

Comment: you wrote "yet it can route analogue signals". how is the "analogue switch IC" route a continuous signal like a sinusoid input all the way to its output by switching action of the transistors in it?

Comment: @161776 it does so by turning on and off transistors i.e. making them conduct with low impedance or go fairly high impedance in the off state.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is so-called analog or digital ic.The definition is talking about the relationship between ICs in circuit.Example: An flip-flop based ic can produce a square pulse and it can be used as a bit stream in digital circuit while it also can be used as an fm modulator for the analog application.

Comment: How can a digital circuit with transistors used as switch process analog signals and output analog signals. I dont understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Digital IC or Analogue IC are not special words for special usage.
For example if output or input range of an IC is within digital ranges you can say it digital IC aside what happens in it and similar for analogue.
Another example if an IC produces a signal by digital modulation you can say it digital although it may contain some analouge processing in it.

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly substrates optimized for different applications. But yeah, mixed technologies are not uncommon. An MCU may have an ADC, or an ADC may have SPI. I wouldn't worry too much about it, as you learn more about electronics it'll come together.