# Why does the output of NOT gate (in a 74LS04 IC) equal to one when the input wire is not connected to anywhere?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

I have a `74LS04` integrated circuit, like this:

[image]
<sup>[source](http://www.learnerswings.com/2014/07/control-7404-not-gate-ic-using-arduino.html)</sup>

I put this IC on a Bread Board and connect the negative and positive parts of the Bread Board to negative and positive parts of a **5-volt source**, respectively. Then, I connect the pin number 14 to the positive line of the Bread Board and the pin number 7 to the negative line of the Bread Board (representing Ground).

Now if I connect pin number 1 to the negative line of Bread Board (thus feeding 0 to the NOT gate) and measure the first NOT Gate's output (pin number 2) with a voltmeter, I see the number 5 volt (meaning 1). And if I connect pin number 1 to the positive line of Bread Board (thus feeding 1 to the NOT gate) and measure the voltage of pin number 2, I see the number 0 volt (meaning 0). So far everything makes sense.

But if I leave the pin number 1 **unconnected** and measure the voltage of pin number 2, I see the number 2.6 volt, which I've been told that it means 1. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You are not driving the inverter with valid input so don't expect to get a valid ouput either. So don't leave pins unconnected as they are floating at some unspecified voltage and the inverter migh be halfway between on and off states. And you cannot see with a voltmeter if it is even stable or does it oscillate at some high frequency.

Floating TTL inputs tend to be biased high by the internal circuitry, thus a floating input should be read as logic high by the chip, which means the expected output from the inverter should be logic low.

Comment: But I was always getting `2.6 volt` while other teams were always getting a `0`. Its consistency with every time I tried (despite seeming random across different Bread Boards) seems odd to me.

Comment: The phrase "garbage-in-garbidge-out" applies very much here.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani: Did you try a different chip? It sounds like the one you're working with might be damaged.

Comment: @DaveTweed I didn't, but I can try it tomorrow when I have access to the lab. Is the output determined randomly?

Comment: Maybe they have different chips? Maybe your chip is damaged by ESD? Maybe other teams made errors and chips were unpowered? Maybe other teams put a bypass capacitor over supply pins so it did not oscillate? Maybe breadboard is damaged and has short circuits or leakage current? Is your chip plain old 7404, 74LS04, 74HC04 or some other type, because it matters a lot? Did you try other gates than pins 1&2, like pins 3&4? But seriously, for a standard 7404, I would expect the output to be low when input is unconnected, due to the internal circuitry.

Comment: As @Justme said: first find out if the output is oscillating. (Have you got any EMC sources nearby like a  big power supply.)

Comment: @Justme It's a `74LS04` chip, edited the question. I should've done those before asking. I'll do them tomorrow.

Comment: @Oldfart I tried feeding 1 to pin1, then feeding 0, then leaving it open and measure, and then doing it in reverse (feed 0, feed 1, then measure) to see if its dependent on its previous input, which is not. And I guess it makes sense.

Comment: @Justme Our professor said he expected the result for `74LS04` (when leaving it unconnected) to be 1 (as the result our team got), though I think he might be just testing us. Are there any articles I can read to understand why you would expect the output to be low?

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani It is common knowledge. Just search the internet what is default for floating LS TTL inputs, and you will find references such as books that state that floating LS TTL inputs tend to be read as high and the reason in the internal circuitry why it is so. It means that inverter output tends to be low.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani Don't fall into the 'digital' trap; all logic gates are analog - they just happen to be either at the positive or negative rails at the output under normal condition. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/330851/a-question-about-analog-ic-vs-digital-ic that has an image of the internal circuitry of the 74LS04 (one gate shown).

Comment: do you have a CMOS IC? And, to reduce risk of oscillation, install 0.1uF right across the IC (pins 7 and 14).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't consider expecting a 74-Series TTL gate to register a high-impedance line as an input high to be the best design practice but in principal it is true.

Consider the schematic of one gate in a [74LS04](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls04-sp.pdf):

[image: Source: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls04-sp.pdf]

Note, the input diode is cut-off whether the input is high (Vi=5V) or floating (Vi=Hi-Z).

With a floating input, you would expect to see an output of logic low.

Answer (score 1):

Also, floating inputs can cause the output driver to be in an intermediate state with both output transistors partly turned on. This causes current to flow through the totem pole and will heat the device, possible causing reduced life or failure.

Always drive your inputs people.